# Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

In `Ability.rb`:

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new
  if user.role? :Agent
    can :manage, ServiceRequest
  elsif user.role? :Punching_team
    can :manage, SrDocument
  end
```

In `service_request_controller`:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

In `sr_documents_controller`:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

In `application_controller`:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  redirect_to root_url, :alert => exception.message
end
```

In routes:

```
devise_scope :user do
  root to: "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

In log:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

I am using `cancan` gem in my application.I want to set authorization in such a way that if a user is an 'Agent' then he/she should access `ServiceRequest` model and for 'Punching_team' type then he/she should access `SrDocument` model.But when i am login with an agent, getting an infinite loop.Which gives me errors like `Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected.Please help me out.